# Run PHP into Subversion setup (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, svn, webserver, dreamhost

I am trying to setup subversion for team web development... I was able to setup it to svn.mydomain.com (with dreamhost), but when I try to access it with my browser (to see the result of the website) all I see is the file list ... PHP is not executed.

Is there anything I do wrong? I know the SVN setup is working because I am able to commit, import, export, etc.

Also, I wonder where on the FTP I should be able to see the actual files; the folder of the svn.mydomain.com is empty.

Answer (score -1):

You must checkout the subversion project

in ubuntu: `svn checkout svn.mydomain.com ./`

Comment: This way, the project will end up on my root domain? Is that it?

Comment: It works not only on Ubuntu (it works on Windows and other Linux systems); you didn't provide any reference.